# How to center the heading of bibliography without affecting the alignment of it in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, alignment

I have used `\usepackage[nottoc, other]{tocbibind}` and then `\renewcommand{tocbibname}{\centering REFERENCES}` to center the heading. It puts the heading in the center within the body but then ruins the alignment in ToC.
Is there any other way to do it without affecting the alignment of ToC. And I would also like change the heading from "Bibliography" to "REFERENCE".

Here's the code I've used

```
\documentclass[lettersize,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[nottoc,other]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\tocbibname}{\centering REFERENCES}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\newpage
\section{ABC}
\section{XYZ}
\newpage
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The position of the bibliography title is almost certainly defined in the document class, but since you haven't told us which one you're using, it's very hard to help.  Our crystal balls are not responding.

Comment: `\centering` in `\…name` will be used whenever this name is used, e.g., in the ToC, in the page header … So as general: Adding a formatting in language dependent terms can always result in unwanted side effects and should be avoided unless you really know, what you are doing (i.e. where the name is used).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use package `titlesec` to redefine the formatting of not numbered sections or patch `tocbibind` to center all not numbered headings with ToC entries, as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nottoc,other]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\tocbibname}{REFERENCES}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\toc@section}[2]{%
  \@nameuse{#1}*{\centering #2\prw@mkboth{#2}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{#2}%
}
% Following is only needed for report or book and without option other but not with article (as used in this example).
\renewcommand{\toc@chapter}[1]{%
  \chapter*{\centering #1}\prw@mkboth{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{ABC}
\cite{aksin}
\section{XYZ}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]